# How to remove GreatSave4U extension from Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, windows-7

I am using Google chrome in my Windows7 machine, i found some extension **GreatSave4U** in Google Chrome browser which i tried to remove by the following way..

1. Launch the browser and simultaneously tap Alt+F.
2. In the appeared menu move to Tools and then click Extensions.
3. Click the recycle bin icon on the right of the undesirable plugin and select Remove.

It is removed and i am not getting any ads but when i am closing that instance of browser and restarting browser it again appear in extension list and displaying unwanted ads like Virus.

How to fix this issue?

**EDIT:-**

Contents of `chrome://version/`

```
> Google Chrome 41.0.2272.101 (Official Build) m
> Revision  0c9975a0ae4c55b8530ec3193c21ed54b96cbe88-refs/branch-heads/2272@{#437}
> OS    Windows  Blink  537.36 (@191727) JavaScript V8 4.1.0.21
> Flash 17.0.0.134 User Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101
> Safari/537.36 Command
> Line  "C:\Users\sjoshi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
> --flag-switches-begin --enable-experimental-extension-apis --flag-switches-end Executable Path    C:\Users\sjoshi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> Profile Path  C:\Users\sjoshi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
> Data\Default Variations   74785582-3f4a17df 22fd1d6c-7461cf66
> e950616e-ca7d8d80 e9f4800b-39c30599 8afebf76-77d7928 19f73432-ca7d8d80
> 76b48ab8-a2567007 c70841c8-a2567007 195ce1b5-d93a0620
> 4b406b23-3f4a17df 1d3ad72e-3f4a17df 9e5c75f1-8b3c5d32
> f79cb77b-3d47f4f4 ca65a9fe-91ac3782 4ea303a6-7a1ae6ac
> 61544484-ca7d8d80 a6f20d5c-6355c4e9 7aa46da5-ca7d8d80
> 9736de91-ca7d8d80 ea1014b7-dd21eb5a 244ca1ac-4ad60575
> f47ae82a-746c2ad4 3ac60855-486e2a9c f296190c-4c073154
> 4442aae2-75cb33fc ed1d377-e1cc0f14 75f0f0a0-a5822863 e2b18481-6bdfffe7
> e7e71889-4ad60575 58a405fc-669a04e0 cbf0c14e-bf3e6cfd
> af644a23-3f4a17df
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an extension that is loaded via the command line. Edit your shortcut (right-click, properties) and look for the `--load-extension=C:\path\to\extension` flag, and remove this one. This will prevent the extension from being loaded.

That fixes the symptom, but not the problem. You have to find why you got this piece of malware on your system in the first place. If you're lucky, the damage is limited to the installation of an unwanted extension. If the malware is a bit more sophiscated, the only way to recover (i.e. regain trust in your system) is to perform a full reinstallation of Windows, because you have no reason to trust your system any more.

Comment: But if i will prevent to load extension it mean it will not load other extension as well?

Comment: @subodh It will only prevent this  specific extension from being sideloaded.

Comment: thanks but after right click i didnot found what you mentioned in ur answer

Comment: @subodh Could you visit `chrome://version` and share a screenshot or paste the contents of that page?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: @subodh The command-line flags look normal. I suggest to follow the tips at http://malwaretips.com/blogs/greatsave4u-virus-removal/